# Hive - killing job as end user

Tags: hive

Is there a way to kill Hive job as end user (without admin rights)?

If no, is there a easy way to find a job run by specific user? Or add additional info to every query run by user in order to identify it and write some script to kill a specific job?

Regards,
Karol

Answer (score 0):

hadoop job -kill [job_id]

You can find the job ID once the job gets triggered in Hive or from the Job Tracker

Comment: Great...now read my question again plz :) key words are: 'end-user' and 'without admin rights'.

Comment: lOl..anyone can kill a job. their own job or others job as well..  To kill a job one doesnt need admin rights.. 